# How to add third column to the drupal view (Format: Table), col3=col1/col2 with sorting by col3?

Tags: views

I am using Views module. The view has two columns.
In the third column, I want to "col1/col2", but the most important is that the column can be sorted

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are using Table format, you should have 1 col for each visible Field you have added to your View. So if you have two Cols, add a third Field.

Comment: I do not have a third field. I can get it if I divide the first field into the second. I even did it with the help of custom handler, but I still need sorting.

Comment: You are pulling in 2 fields of data and want it split into 3 cols? How far into the process are you? Can you change how you are collecting the data so it matches how you plan to use it?

You may want to create two instances of the field and change them using the Rewrite Field option for each.

Comment: http://joxi.ru/EA4XlM1tVJQJAb
I have only 1 and 2 fields in DB. Third field I calculate programmatically.
Now i need to sort it